# how to automatically save server.log when the date change

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6, jboss-eap-7

I am new to jboss eap so i don`t know much. My question is about the server.log the default is "handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd" this function will save the log however when the day change its not automatic will save. I want a function that when the date change the server.log will save automatically. Is there a settings like that?

Comment: Could you be more specific with your query? Do you want to enable log rotation on basis of date? Are you using periodic rotating log handler?

Comment: If possible share your configuration for the logging subsystem aswell.

Comment: That should already do that. However it will only rotate once a log message has been written on the new date.

Comment: @SudhishNair  still have the default value which is handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd. I want the log server automatically save once the day also change.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins yes that should that, but its not automatically save once the day change

Comment: What do you mean by "not automatically saved"? With that suffix pattern the file should be rotated daily once a log message is written. So `server.log` for 2019.01.18 would end up being moved to `server.log.2019-01-18` and a new `server.log` would be created. There are potential locking issues on Windows however if another process as the file open.